# Azure powershell set tags using bicep

Tags: powershell, azure-pipelines, azure-bicep

I am using a serie of tags from my azure pipelines, from a `yml` file to a `template`

```
tags:
      environment: 'Development'
      owner: 'owername'
      chargeCode: 'x001'
      product: 'productname'
      supportteam: 'supportTeamName'
```

At the moment to receive it into my template, I get it as an object, like:

```
parameters:
- name: tags
  type: object
  default: {}
```

Also, I am trying to fix the json string with a `powershell` task:

```
- powershell: |
    $mayarrstr= @"
    ${{ convertToJson(parameters.tags) }}
    "@
    Write-Host $mayarrstr

    $mayarrstr = $mayarrstr -replace '"', "'"

    Write-Host $mayarrstr


    $jsonObject = $mayarrstr | ConvertFrom-Json

    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=tags]$jsonObject"

  displayName: 'Set Tags Variable'
```

But at the moment to receive it into my bicep file. I am using:

`param tags object = {}`

But every time I am receiving it, it says that the string can't be parsed to a json, or error in the character `[0] ={`

How can I set the `tags` to my resources if I have to use `AzureCLI@2` to parse the string to `object` ?

Comment: Why do you want to define tags for your azure resources in your CI platform? That just tightly couples your infrastructure to your CI platform for no reason. Wouldn't it make more sense to use Bicep parameters files for managing tags? Like, if I run a deployment of your infrastructure from another tool, why *wouldn't* I want to get the same sets of tags on my resources?

Comment: yeah you have few options: create a json/parameter file. pass the tag as string and create the object in the bicep file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to pass the JSON string as a parameter to the bicep file:

1. In the bicep file, you can configure like as below.

```
param tags object = json(tagJsonObj)
```

2. In the pipeline, you can configure like as below.

```yaml
parameters:
- name: tags
  type: object
  default:
    environment: Development
    owner: owername
    chargeCode: x001
    product: productname
    supportteam: supportTeamName

. . .
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Set tags json object'
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: |
      $tagsJsonStr = @"
      ${{ convertToJson(parameters.tags) }}
      "@
      Write-Host $tagsJsonStr
      $tagsJsonStr = $tagsJsonStr.Replace('"', '\"').Replace("`r", "").Replace("`n", "")
      Write-Host $tagsJsonStr
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=tags;]$tagsJsonStr"

- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Bicep deployment'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: MyArmConnection
    scriptType: pscore
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: 'az deployment group create --resource-group {resource-group} --template-file {path-to-bicep} --parameters tagJsonObj=''$(tags)'''
```

---